# WPF. Nested modal dialogs

Tags: wpf

I have several windows (MainWindow, Window1, Window2) in WPF application
Every window has a button that shows next window (MainWindow -> Window1 -> Window2) in modal mode. Something like:

**MainWindow Button Handler**

```
 Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
 Window1 w = new Window1();
 w.ShowDialog();
 Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

**Window1 Button Handler**

```
 Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
 Window2 w = new Window2();
 w.ShowDialog();
 Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

The problem is - when Window2 is closed (Alt + F4) not only Window1 ends it "w.ShowDialog()" method call, but MainWindow too! When Window2 is closed - both windows (Window1 + MainWindow) become visible simultaneously!

Why MainWindow becomes visible and what can I do to avoid this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hide the windows, you might as well use the `Show()` method and handle the `Closed` event instead of calling `ShowDialog()`:

```
Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
Window1 w = new Window1();
w.Closed += (ss, ee) => Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
w.Show();
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Finally I ended with your solution, though it is very strange - ShowDialog doesn't work in WPF the same way as in Windows Forms. Windows Forms allows me to have nested modal dialogs the way I expected